# how to write a function which calls a Simulink file in it.. i don't knot how to call it?

Tags: matlab, makefile, simulink

I want to pass inputs to a simulink function and write simulink's output to a vector in M-file. How can I do it? I want to know how to call a simulink function in a M-file?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I have searched it on google and matlab mathswork websites. But i could not find my requirments.

Comment: I have searched it on google and MATLAB's Mathswork websites. But I could not find my requirments. I have also called help sim. But its not clear that how to pass more than 1 inputs to a simulink in a m-file.

Comment: You question is far to broad to answer effectively.  (Are you talking about input parameters; input signals, input ports, from Workspace, from File blocks?) But in essence, if you know how to run your model by pressing the run button on your Simulink model, then running it using sim is almost identical.  Be more specific and you should get a more specific answer.